# Reverse Part of a List

Tags: list, python-3.x, reverse

Take list `foo`

```
foo = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

How can I reverse only the elements of indices x to y within the list?
For example:

```
x = 1
y = 5
# reverse foo[x:y]
foo = [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Slice it out, reverse it, and concatenate everything back together.

Answer (score 4):

Python allows you to [assign to slices](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=assignment#slicings)

> Slicings may be used as expressions or as targets in assignment or del
>   statements

thus it's possible to do everything on one line:

```
foo[x:y] = foo[y-1:x-1:-1]
```

Note that`foo[y-1:x-1:-1]` has the same meaning as `foo[x:y][::-1]`.

Comment: it doesn't seems to work when x is pointing the index 0

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as:

```
foo[x:y] = foo[y - 1:x - 1:-1]
```

For example:

```
>>> foo = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> foo[1:5] = foo[4:0:-1]
>>> foo
[5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: can I get that in terms of x and y?

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse(l, x, y):
    l[x:y+1] = l[y:x-1:-1]

foo = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
x = 1
y = 4

reverse(foo, x, y)
print(foo) # [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 10, 11, 12]
```